# Need to enter more data for user sign up in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Firebase. I was looking at the Firebase documentation and it seems good. But one thing I've noticed is that when I register/sign up my users, I can only get their email ID and password.

However, for my app, I need my users to enter more details like name, address, phone, and some other details. How can I do this?

I thought maybe I can use the real time database, but then I didn't know how to match the users with their respective details from the realtime database. Please give me some ideas on how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You're right.
In order to save some user data, you will have to use Realtime Database. There are few properties you can assign to user like email, photoURL, displayName but for more than that you have to use database.

Hope it helps, here is a way I am doing it:
I created "users" node in database and every time new user registers, new entry with his uid gets inserted. Check screenshot below:

[image]

So every time you need to get user data, just call child at "users" node with given "current user uid".

Comment: Please can you add an example/snippet of how you do that?

Answer (score 1):

On Success of registration , get all the details and update/create the information in firebase database.

```
 final String emailId = mEditTextEmail.getText().toString() ;
 String password = mEditTextPassword.getText().toString() ;
 firebaseRef.createUser(emailId, password, new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String,Object>>() {
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap) {

                            User user = new User();
                            user.setUid(stringObjectMap.get("uid").toString());
                            user.setEmail(emailId);
                            user.setProfileStatus(User.NEW);
                            firebaseRef.child("Users").child(user.getUid()).setValue(user);
                            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("email",mEditTextEmail.getText().toString());
                            startActivity(intent);

                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"You are Successfully Registered in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Login to continue..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
```